# Yammer - is it possible to activate a user via api?

Tags: yammer

I need to be able to activate a group of users programmatically. You can enable users for Yammer, but they don't actually get activated until they login the first time.

I need to simulate this first-time login via Rest API or any other method possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By design, user activation is done at first login only. There isn't any (supported) API endpoint that can be used to activate users. Perhaps there might be other ways to achieve your aim if you shed more light into why you're looking to activate users programmatically?